# Is there a way to develop a multiple controlled X or Z gate on Qiskit without using ancillary qubits?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit

I know for instance I can derive a cccX gate using 2 Toffoli gates on 5 qubit wire or ccccX with 3 Toffoli gates and 7 qubits and so on. you will notice the depth is increasing as the number of control qubits increase, that is for every additional c, there are 2 additional qubits. Is there a better way I can derive these multiple controlled x gate using fewer resources (gates and qubits)?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/terra/qis_adv/quantum_walk.ipynb) Qiskit tutorial does what I think you're looking for; with the `cnx()` function. It uses [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016) paper to decompose the CNOT gate without ancilla qubits.

Let me know, if this helps you.

Comment: Replaced the depreciated `cu3` gates with `cu` gates and it worked perfectly. Thanks.