# Can you decompose a 4-qubit Toffoli gate (CCCX) into basic gates without an ancillary state?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, toffoli-gate

I have a problem relevant to the circuit depth of a $\text{CCCX}$ gate, but I can't find any literature on decomposing this gate into basic gates without an ancillary qubit. Is this possible, and are there any sources where I can read about this?

Comment: Can you define *basic gates*?

Comment: $H$, $T$, $T^\dagger$, and CNOT.

Comment: Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/is-there-a-way-to-develop-a-multiple-controlled-x-or-z-gate-on-qiskit-without-us

Answer (score 4):

The seminal paper [Barenco *et al.*, Elementary gates for quantum computation](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.quant-ph/9503016) is a great resource for decompositions of many quantum gates, including multi-control Toffoli gates, into elementary gates. (Notably, it contains both constructions with and without ancillas.)